# OutOfMemory while deploying war on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, out-of-memory

i get the following error when i try to deploy a war (built with 'grails war') on a tomcat server. Unfortunately there is no other message in the logfile except this:

```
Nov 25, 2013 3:44:54 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean invoke
SEVERE: Exception invoking method check
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:661)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantUtf8.<init>(ConstantUtf8.java:47)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:125)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:209)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2118)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1994)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1960)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1319)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1461)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445)
```

How can i get more information about this error?

Notes:

- the grails app is working locally without any issues
- other grails apps are working on the same server without problems (all with version 2.2.0, the new one is on 2.3)
- i already tried to extend the memory heap ... no improvement

Thank you

Comment: I guess it is a dependency problem

Comment: Enable jmx on your server and try to connect jconsole, might help you understand what's going on.

Comment: May i know which IDE you are using?

Comment: i dont use any ide on my server :)

Answer (score 0):

What Tomcat version you use? If you for example run Debian Wheezy box, the version available from packages is *7.0.28*. It has some serious bugs about traversing classpaths for scanning for annotations (at least that's what I noticed after reading few other questions on SO and bug reports). I think it was fixed somewhere ~ *7.0.34*. I had an exactly same problem and noticed that everything runs fine on newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
1- Create setenv.sh in Tomcat(8||9)/bin/setenv.sh 

    export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms512m"
    export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx2048m"
    export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

2- chamod a+x setenv.sh  
3- execute ./setenv.sh  
4- ./startup.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to setenv.sh the following option in CATALINA_OPTS `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` it will print heap dump when your deploy will fall down with OOM, which you can analyze by such utilities as [JVisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/download.html) or [MemoryAnalyzer](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php). After investigation of heap dump you can make decision:

- Fix an issue which produce OutOfMemory
- Increase heap size (by setting [-Xmx in CATALINA_OPTS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61181991/12309398)) in case you can't fix an issue.